# how to get the header of a csv file and print it as a column using linux?

Tags: linux, csv

I am trying to get the header or the first line of a csv file and print it as a column.

file example: test.txt
name^lastname^address^zipcode^phonenumber

expected result:

```
name
lastname
address
zipcode
phonenumber
```

Answer (score 7):

Just do this

```
head -n1 test.txt | tr , '\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for i in `cat test.txt`; do
IFS='^'
arr=($i)
for col in "${arr[@]}"; do
    echo "$col"
done
break;
done
```

Comment: awesome!!! it worked. sorry, but is there a way to not include echo "${arr[0,1,2,3,4]} coz the header is really long abt 58 fields.

Comment: I edited script to print more fields, hope this helps :)

Comment: it worked :) thank you so much. cant vote up coz i dont have enough reputation but u saved my day.

Answer (score 1):

`head` prints `n` lines of a file, `tr` replaces all occurrences of a first char with a second char

```
head -n1 test.txt | tr '^' '\n'
```